# how to check if the give firebase reference doesnot contain any value or it is empty

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-progressbar

I want to dismiss progress bar if given firebase reference does not contain any input.
if the given reference has no data then progress bar keeps loading, how to fix this.

I want to dismiss progress bar if deliveryBoyReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() ..
function is not called

recyclerView = output.findViewById(R.id.list_of_all_delivery_area_recyclerview);
        deliveryBoyItems = new ArrayList<>();

```
    final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    pd.setMessage("loading");
    pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    pd.show();

    firebaseStorage=FirebaseDatabaseReference.getStorageINSTANCE();
    storageReference=firebaseStorage.getReference("DeliveryBoyImage/");


    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabaseReference.getDatabaseInstance();
    deliveryBoyReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("DELIVERYBOY");

    deliveryBoyReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            DeliveryBoyReference deliveryBoyReference = dataSnapshot.getValue(DeliveryBoyReference.class);
            deliveryBoyItems.add(deliveryBoyReference);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            pd.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Log.i("fail","fail");

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Log.i("fail","fail");

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.i("fail1","fail");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot dismiss a progress bar with a `ChildEventListener`, since the `onChildAdded` method is only called when a child actually exist. So if you want to dismiss the progress bar, add an additional `ValueEventListener` that is guaranteed to fire:

```
deliveryBoyReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        pd.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.i("fail1","fail");
    }
});
```

This will not lead to extra bandwidth being used, since Firebase will actually under the hood only retrieve the data for both listener once.

Comment: If I push a child, then the complete list of children would be called, thus increasing the number of hits unnecessarily and would reduce the efficiency of the app. But instead, when I'm using ref.addChildEventListener, this doesn't happen.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying there. The above approach works, and is used by many apps that I know: using a `ChildEventListener` for the granular updates, and a `ValueEventListener` for hiding the progress bar. My answer shows how little extra code it is, and explains why this does not cause (significant) extra bandwidth consumption.